# Big Query pretty print String values are escaped with \

Tags: google-bigquery

I used `TO_JSON_STRING(value[, pretty_print])` function to get the pretty print of struct in BigQuery. However, the output JSON contains string escape characters with '\'. Also I see control characters are also escaped.

Big Query has already published about struct with the following statement

> Invalid UTF-8 field names might result in unparseable JSON. String values are escaped according to the JSON standard. Specifically, ", \, and the control characters from U+0000 to U+001F are escaped.

What can I do?

Comment: You post doesn't have a specific question, you are describing the output of your query.  Are you having trouble loading the output to another system?

Comment: Yes..while I'm trying to ingest this data into data warehouse like snowflake, its giving incorrect results as the json looks like this: {\"searchnumber\":1,\"time\":0,\"hour\":20,\"minute\" .... instead of  {"searchnumber":1,"time":0,"hour":20,"minute"

Comment: You probably want help on Snowflake, not BigQuery.  https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008NsdsBSAR/does-anyone-have-an-elegant-solution-for-dealing-with-backslashes-in-raw-ndjson